# Winform datagridview numeric sorting

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am really frustrated to have to ask this question. It seems that there are several other questions on the very same topic. So, instead of asking 'how to do it' I'll try the 'What am I doing wrong' angle.

I have a simple datagridview with unbound xml data, right now just 4 columns and 4-6 rows. One of the columns contain numbers and I'd like to sort the data on this. 
When importing the xml, all data is string data.
When I press a button:

- The ValueType of the column is cast to Integer
- The rows are looped, a random number between 1 and 20 is generated and inserted
- The rows are sorted

Like this:

```
    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        dataGridView1.Columns[2].ValueType = typeof(int);
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            row.Cells[2].Value = rnd.Next(1, 20);
        }
        dataGridView1.Sort(dataGridView1.Columns[2], ListSortDirection.Descending);
    }
```

The sorting works fine as long as all rows have an equal amount of digits; so (9, 5, 3, 1) sorts correctly and (19, 17, 16, 14) does too, but when there are both 1 and 2 digit numbers (4, 17, 15, 13) the sorting messes up and 4 is somehow a higher number than 17.
I have tried to add

```
MessageBox.Show(dataGridView1.Columns[2].ValueType.Name);
```

...to make sure that the ValueType is actually Int32, and it is...

So why is it not sorting correctly?
Please help...

Comment: Sort the data, not the control. I suggest you import your XML file to a DataTable, using the `DataTable.DefaultView.Sort` property to sort the data. Or a `List<class>`. LINQ's OrderBy/OrderByDescending/ThenBy/ThenByDescending methods can be combined to sort/filter. This implies that the data is imported using the correct types. It'ld also help to sort the control as you expect, until you need to sort/filter more than one column at the same time.

Comment: You have only prepared to column to receive ints from a datasource; the cells are still TextBoxCells. - You will need to do this: 1) Make sure to have values in all rows 2) set sorting to `programmatic` for that column and 3) code the `SortCompare` event. Example: `private void dataGridView1_SortCompare(object sender, DataGridViewSortCompareEventArgs e)
{
    var n1 = Convert.ToInt32(e.CellValue1);
    var n2 = Convert.ToInt32(e.CellValue2);
    e.SortResult = n2.CompareTo(n1);
    e.Handled = true;
}`

Comment: @Jimi - I dont understand what you mean by '_sort the data, not the control_' - the  `dataGridView1.Sort(dataGridView1.Columns[2], ListSortDirection.Descending);`  does sort the data... I can add several more rows and do random numbers in them, and they are clearly sorted, just not the way I want them to be, There is a small arrow on the column headline that shows that is is sorted and adding more lines are sorted (wrongly) dynamically...

Comment: @TaW - I have also tried this. I have set the eventhandler SortHandler in the GUI to the method `dataGridView1_SortCompare` - I expected this to fire when I click on the column headline (also I expected clicking on the headline to sort correctly), but the event never fires.

Comment: You're sorting the formatted content displayed in a control. You have to know what type is the *real* data contained in a Column and convert its value to a specific type to sort it *correctly*. If you deserialize your data, strong typed, to a collection (a DataTable, possibly), you speed up all the operation an you also can use the already existing tools to sort/filter etc. your data without any hassle or the need to convert the type o each column. Note that you can define a column's type, but, if your data is composed of all strings, you have a problem. Correct this and all is good.

Comment: I am sure you are both right - I simply don't know what to do to remedy the problem. I cannot understand why clicking the column header does not sort the column content as integer, when I have cast the column to integer with `dataGridView1.Columns[2].ValueType = typeof(int);` - Sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: If you want to let the user use the columnheaders do not set the column to `programmatic` but keep it at `automatic` ! (your question was not clear about the intention) - The event to code is the `dgv.SortCompare`. The code example is tested and works fine here. If you want to sort by other columns and/or varying types/rules the code should include a switch on the columnindex and use suitable convert functions!

Comment: @TaW - At this point, I am willing to sort any way possible! I figure that if I can get it to sort correctly in any situation, I will be able to figure it out from there...  I learned about the meaning of `programmatic` by trying.  Would you be able to provide a functioning code example - I might have stared myself blind at the problem at this time.

Comment: I have provided a functioning code example! You don't need any more than the code I posted! Note that you need to make sure the event is actually hooked up. DoubleClick the event name in the events pane in the dgv properties window! Use the debugger to test if the code enters the event!!

Comment: I have looked at many of the other posts with much the same questions, and I am sure that more than one of them really had the same problem that I did. @Jimi really nailed it in the very first comment - I was sorting the control, not the data. Only after the help of Taw did I realise what was wrong. The XML data I was importing was generic string, without a schema. After importing them to a dataset, they were still string, and thus can only be sorted ad such. Now I am importing them as the correct types, and I can sort correctly!
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Good job, then. You could post your findings and the code you produced as an answer to a new question.